# "It's a harsh truth" vs. "it's the harsh truth" in context

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Would you tell me if I need to use *a* or *the* before *harsh truth* in the sentence below.

> When you are trying to lose weight, you have to make sacrifices, such as cutting down on or cutting out completely highly processed food. That's just **a**/**the** harsh truth.

I've noticed that *truth* is usually used with *the*, but I've always come across instances where it's been used with *a*. Are both possible in the context I provided, if so is there a nuance of difference between *a* and *the* there?

Comment: Both are commonly used: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+harsh+truth%2Cthe+harsh+truth&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20harsh%20truth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20harsh%20truth%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both can be used, and both are grammatically valid. The indefinite article "a" would be more likely to be used when the speaker sees the "truth" being expressed as one of several truths. When the speaker is focused on a single "harsh truth", s/he is more likely to use "the". The difference is a matter of emphasis.

Examples:

> It's a harsh truth that one doesn't always get what one wants.

> When one thing after another goes wrong on the same day, a person often reacts badly, and that's the harsh truth.

Comment: @Prem Thanks for the heads up.